# How to create a simple closed curve homotopic to the trefoil knot?

Tags: differential-geometry

How to create a simple closed curve that is homotopic to the trefoil knot

$\overrightarrow{\alpha} (t)= \left ( \left (3+ \cos (3t) \right) \cos (2t),\left (3+ \cos (3t) \right) \sin (2t),\sin (3t) \right)$

with a total curvature of $4 \pi + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$ ?